# Opening .xlsx using Office XP Interop

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, ms-office

I'm trying to do COM automation with Microsoft Office Excel and it has to be compatible with as many systems as possible. It's a relatively basic program that takes a text file and uses it to populate most of a pre-made Excel form (.xlsx) which the user can then sign off on and save.

I only have Visual Studio 2008, so instead of using the "Embed Interop" option, I'm using late binding. It is being programmed in C# and uses .Net Framework 3.5.

The test system is running Windows XP SP3 with Office XP (the oldest one we will be supporting), with the Office 2007 compatibility pack and .Net 3.5 installed. I am able to open the .xlsx file normally in the file browser, but when trying to open it through my program it gives an error saying that "The file is in an unrecognizable format", etc.

I figure that the problem lies in opening the workbook, here's the code I have for that:

```
//Add a new workbook.
Parameters = new Object[15];
Parameters[0] = openFileDialog1.FileName;

for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
    if(i == 2)
        Parameters[2] = true; //make file read only
    else
        Parameters[i] = Missing.Value; //default on the rest
}

objBook_Late = objBooks_Late.GetType().InvokeMember("Open",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objBooks_Late, Parameters);
```

I have tested this on Excel 2010 and 2007 so far, and they both have worked fine, so I'm not entirely sure why this causes an error on WinXP. I would use an older .xls file if I could, but unfortunately it's not up to me.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When I do this, I have `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook _excelWorkbook = null;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets _workSheets = null;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet _work = null;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range _range = null;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range _notesLineRange = null;`  all over the place.  Can you include some more details?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Meredith! Yes I made sure that it was being included as well as instantiating all the relevant objects. I'd post the full code if you want but it's a bit lengthy considering I used late binding. However, I found the answer to it and it was (embarrassingly enough) unrelated to the program. See the answer below for what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after some more research I finally fixed it. Just as an update, this error was coming up even if if you did File >> Open from within Excel, so it wasn't my program causing the error.

It turns out that my test bed was having some residual problems from an Office 2007 install. It was trying to open .xlsx files with office 2007 even though it wasn't installed anymore. I went into the Control Panel >> Folder Options >> File Types and changed .xlsx to the Microsoft open XML converter, and it worked!